# Python Linked Priority Queue using Node Chains

Tags: python, nodes

```
class _PQ_Node:

    def __init__(self, value, _next):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Initializes a priority queue node that contains a copy of value
        and a link to the next node in the priority queue
        Use: node = _PQ_Node(value, _next)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Parameters:
            value - value value for node (?)
            _next - another priority queue node (_PQ_Node)
        Returns:
            a new Priority_Queue object (_PQ_Node)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        self._value = deepcopy(value)
        self._next = _next


class Priority_Queue:

    def __init__(self):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Initializes an empty priority queue.
        Use: pq = Priority_Queue()
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Returns:
            a new Priority_Queue object (Priority_Queue)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        self._front = None
        self._rear = None
        self._count = 0



    def insert(self, value):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        A copy of value is inserted into the priority queue.
        Values are stored in priority order. 
        Use: pq.insert(value)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Parameters:
            value - a data element (?)
        Returns:
            None
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """

        # Your code here
        
        new_node = _PQ_Node(value,None)
        
        if self._count == 0:
            self._front = new_node
            self._rear = new_node
        else:
            current = self._front 
            #next = self._front._next
            while current is not None and current._value < value:
                current = current._next
            if current is not None and current._value > value:
                new_node._next = current
                current = new_node
                self._rear = new_node
                #holder = current
                #new_node._next = holder
                #self._rear = new_node
                print("Rear : ",self._rear._value)
                print("Current : ",current._value)
                
            else:
                self._rear._next = new_node
                self._rear = new_node
                

        self._count += 1
        return
```

For the python code snipped above I have been atempting to code the insert method the method should work in such a way that each time a new node is inserted, it is inserted in order of values from smallest to largest when attempting to insert 11,22,44,33 in that order the output using a simple iterater outputs 11,22,44 when the appropriate output should be 11,22,33,44 when mapping out the insert method and tracing the varibles it seems like it should work although I am no sure why is isin't if someone could please provide insight to why the output is not showing 33 that would be greatly appriciated

```
PQ = Priority_Queue()
PQ.insert(11)
PQ.insert(22)
PQ.insert(44)
PQ.insert(33)
```

Output: 11,22,44

Correct output: 11,22,33,44

Comment: After `new_node._next = current` you must also find (or remember) the node which has `current` in the `_next` attribute (the node before `current`) and set its `_next` to `new_node`.

Comment: Additionally I guess that `_rear` means the last node of the queue but you set e.g. `self._rear = new_node` without checking if `new_node` really is the last one. If it isn't required you should remove the `_rear` attribute.